# CSS Float property

Tags: html, css

My HTML so far

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
<title>Home</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<style type="text/css" title="currentStyle" media="all">@import url(css/general.css);
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="line"></div>
<div id="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">TV Shows</a></li>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">The Walking Dead</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Grimm</a></li>
            </ul>
        <li><a href="#">Movies</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Action</a>
                <li><a href="#">Comedy</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Thriller</a></li>
            </ul>
        </ul>
    </div>
<div id="content">
    <p>some text blablablaba</p>
</div>
<div id="footer"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My CSS

```
#container
{
border: 1px solid black;
width:95%;
height: 800px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
#line
{
border: 1px solid black;
position: relative;
top: 100px;
}

#header
{
background: url(../header.jpg) no-repeat;
width:150px;
height:150px;
float: left;
position: relative;
top: 50px;
left: 100px;
border: 1px solid black;
z-index: 30;

}

#navigation 
{
position: relative;
float:left;
top: 270px;
width: auto;
height: auto;
border: 1px solid black;
}

#content
{
float:right;
top: 270px;
width: auto;
height: auto;
border: 1px solid black;
}
```

My question: why is my content box if i float it right or left staying at the top of my page? what i read up on float it should be filling up the space next to my navigation. (as my line div is spreading across the page.)
i'd like to have my content in the same position next to my navigation.

(ps. no styling yet plain layout atm)

EDIT: edited my mistake of class="content" to id="content" problem remains

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you used

```
#content
{
    ...
}
```

for `class='content'`!?

you should  use `.content`

and set `position: relative;` for `.content`

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8bz9swpg/)

Comment: Im sorry to occupy your time with that silly mistake. i corrected that by changing my hmtl to `id="content"`  
the problem still remains  though its at the very top of my page rather than next to the navigation